# In Azure policy, is it possible to detect a container/blob creation and apply a deployIfNotExist policy?

Tags: networking, azure, storage

I would like that a blob storage `private endpoint` is created for every storage account which uses blob storage. So for that purpose, i want to use an azure policy with `deployIfNotExist` rules. So if a storage account creates a blob, the azure policy should automatically deploy an private endpoint in **a specified subnet**.

Is that possible? Can **Azure Policy** detect a container/blob creation in an **Azure** storage account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Azure policy cannot see inside a storage account, it can only see the fact that a storage account exists.